# Checking my s3 bucket permissions in bulk via a text word list or csv

Tags: python, boto3, aws-cli

So i'm auditing s3 buckets for work. I can do manual checks for bucket permissions via awscli:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname
```

or via Python using boto3:

```
# list 1st 1000 objects (which I like if it is readable so I can 
#assess risk quickly on larger buckets)
from boto3 import client
bucket_name = input("enter the bucket name")
connection = client('s3')  
for key in connection.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)['Contents']:
    print(key['Key'])
```

My question is, how I can use Python to read a list of my buckets (100+) and check if they are publicly readable or not. I should mention when I audit we use a dummy aws account in one of the ways we check permissions.

I was thinking something like

```
bucketlist = open('buckets.txt', 'r')
```

Now I'm comfortable getting that list to print out but to run the function against each line I got nothing. How can I use either the awscli method or Python boto3 method to check bucket permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the text file with a context manager, load each line as a list, and then loop over all bucket names. Then, define a custom function to check permissions - this will be situation-dependent, but I have included some suggestions and boto documentation links below.

You can use the code you have above with just a slight modification. (Note, this assumes you have one bucket name per line of your file.)

```py
from boto3 import client

def check_bucket_permissions(client, bucket):
    """Function to check bucket permissions.
    What you do here depends on what you want to check.
    Examples given below."""
    pass

# get a list of bucket names (strings)
with open('buckets.txt', 'r') as f:
    bucket_names = f.readlines()

# check each bucket
connection = client('s3')
for bucket_name in bucket_names:
    check_bucket_permissions(client, bucket_name)
```

For the `check_bucket_permissions()` function, you have a few options, depending on what info you are looking for. Two ways of checking who can access buckets are, (1) checking policies, and (2) checking access permissions/access control lists.

[This AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/) gives some background on IAM policies, bucket policies, and access control lists for buckets, but the short version is:

- A bucket policy is an IAM policy document that is attached to the bucket itself, and sets rules for what type of principals (users/groups/roles) can access the bucket's resources, and what type of actions they are allowed to take (read, write, etc.)
- An IAM policy document can also be attached to a principal (user/group/role), and that policy document can set rules for what types of resources (like buckets) can be accessed and what type of actions they are allowed to take
- Bucket ACLs (access control lists) are an older way of specifying bucket permissions (AWS recommends using the IAM approaches above). An ACL is attached to a bucket and defines principals (users/groups/roles) that can access the bucket and what type of access they have.

If you're using the classic IAM policy approach, you can check what IAM policy documents apply to a bucket using the [`get_bucket_policy()` method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=get_bucket_policy#S3.Client.get_bucket_policy):

```
def check_bucket_permissions(client, bucket):
    policy_doc = client.get_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket)
    # parse policy_doc, print or record the result
    return
```

If there are no bucket policies, this will error out with `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (NoSuchBucketPolicy) when calling the GetBucketPolicy operation: The bucket policy does not exist`.

If you want to check bucket ACLs, you can use the [`get_bucket_acl()` method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=get_bucket_acl#S3.Client.get_bucket_acl) instead of the `get_bucket_policy()` method:

```
def check_bucket_permissions(client, bucket):
    acl = client.get_bucket_acl(Bucket=bucket)
    # parse ACL, print or record the result
    return
```

Refer to the documentation for sample JSON responses from each of these methods to figure out how you want to parse the results that are returned.